# HttpClient: limiting connections life

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm using both 4.x and 3.x HttpClient, and I need to limit the total life time of persistent connections. I need them to be reused, but after some time they must be closed, and I can't find a way to do this without writing my own connection manager.
I'm currently using MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager (3.x) and ThreadSafeClientConnManager (4.x).

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.